# SwiftUI Text(): Using ternary conditional not localizing

Tags: swiftui

I'm having trouble printing localized text conditionally. For example, this localizes properly:

```
if valueFromDb.isEmpty {
    Text("value_is_empty") //localized text
} else {
    Text(valueFromDb)
}
```

It prints some text in the user's language if valueFromDb is empty, or it prints valueFromDb as it is if it's not. However, when I try to use the ternary operator it doesn't work:

```
Text(valueFromDb.isEmpty ? "value_is_empty" : valueFromDb)
```

When valueFromDb is empty, it prints "value_is_empty" rather than actual localized text. I get an error (a random one higher up in the hierarchy thanks to SwiftUI) when trying to cast it as LocalizedStringKey.

Edit: To be clear, I know I can do this:

```
valueFromDb.isEmpty ? Text("value_is_empty") : Text(valueFromDb)
```

However, I want to put the ternary conditional inside the Text() brackets because I will do this for several views, and each one will have many modifiers, so the code will become quite bloated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to type inference. You have to declare `myString` to be of type `LocalizedStringKey` and then everything will work as expected.

When you declare:

```
@State var mySrtring: LocalizedStringKey = "whatever"
```

Then:

```
Text(myString.isEmpty ? "error_text_localized" : myString)
```

uses this initializer:

> public init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey,
>                 tableName: String? = nil,
>                 bundle: Bundle? = nil,
>                 comment: StaticString? = nil)

When you declare it like this:

```
@State var mySrtring: String = "whatever"
```

Then:

```
Text(myString.isEmpty ? "error_text_localized" : myString)
```

uses this initialiser:

> public init(verbatim content: String)

Comment: I suspected it was due to something like that. But that doesn't work for me either, because 'myString' refers to user input data, retrieved from the database. I guess my example was not so evident for my use-case so I will update the question.

Comment: Even declaring a String to be LocalizedStringKey doesn't seem to help in my case trying to export the localization. Its ignored. If adding it in manually it might work, but the export step is ignoring the LocalizedStringKey's :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your valueFromDb in quotations, then it should work fine.

```
Text(valueFromDb.isEmpty ? "value_is_empty" : "\(valueFromDb)")
```